# UIImageView not initializing correctly and returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

In my `CathyTaskLogMessageViewController` class, I have this code:

```
import UIKit

class CathyTaskLogMessageViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer!
    @IBOutlet weak var messageTextView: UITextView!
    var defaultPictureButton: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        defaultPictureButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
        defaultPictureButton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 40, 40)
        defaultPictureButton.addTarget(self, action: "defaultPictureButtonTapped:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        defaultPictureButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "defaultPicture"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        defaultPictureButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
        defaultPictureButton.clipsToBounds = true
        defaultPictureButton.exclusiveTouch = true
        self.view.addSubview(defaultPictureButton)

    }

    func defaultPictureButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

        let imageViewerViewController = ImageViewerViewController()
        imageViewerViewController.image = self.defaultPictureButton.imageView!.image
        imageViewerViewController.centerPictureFromPoint(self.defaultPictureButton.frame.origin, ofSize: self.defaultPictureButton.frame.size, withCornerRadius: self.defaultPictureButton.layer.cornerRadius)

    }

}
```

In my `ImageViewerViewController` class, I have the following code:

```
import UIKit

class ImageViewerViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImage!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func centerPictureFromPoint(point: CGPoint, ofSize size: CGSize, withCornerRadius radius: CGFloat) {

        self.imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: point.x, y: point.y, width: size.width, height: size.height))
        self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = radius //I am getting the error here
        self.imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        self.imageView.image = self.image

    }

}
```

And the error that I get is: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. It seems to me that I initialize `imageView` by writing `self.imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: point.x, y: point.y, width: size.width, height: size.height))`. However, it is returning nil. Anybody have a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

If you wouldn't like to initiate the imageView via xib or storyboard. Change the property declaration from:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
```

to

```
var imageView: UIImageView!
```

**weak** causes the imageView is released right away.

Comment: Or if it IS an outlet, hook it up.

Comment: You can keep the @IBOutlet reference but removing the weak clause avoids the compiler to kill the reference to your UIImageView